# Q_OBJECT causes a parse error in my QQuickApp

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-quick, qt-signals, qt6

I'm working on a class derived from QObject, I'm compiling for android and using `android qt6.2.2 Clang arm64_v8a` kit. To the default QQuickApp in qt creator I just added the following header file

MyObject.h

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:

signals:

public slots:

private:

};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <MyObject.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/ParseErrorWorkOn/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

this is the *.pro file:

```
QT += quick
QT += core

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    MyObject.h
```

MyObject has signals and slots then I added `Q_OBJECT`, but compiling I got the following error

```
error: Parse error at "__attribute__"
make: *** [Makefile:700: moc_MyObject.cpp] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I also compiled with Mingw64 for windows and it works fine.
I cleaned up and reran qmake but nothing changed.
Commenting `Q_OBJECT` it compiles fine, but I need signals and slots. How can I fix this? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, I made a mistake setting `qmake system behaviour() when parsing` on `use global setting` instead to set it on `run` in the project configuration window.
[image]